# Ktor: "io.ktor.util.pipeline.ContextDsl" in ktor 2.0

Tags: kotlin, ktor

This annotation is documented [here](https://api.ktor.io/older/1.6.8/ktor-utils/io.ktor.util.pipeline/-context-dsl/index.html?query=annotation%20class%20ContextDsl) but not marked deprecated, however in [the migration guide](https://ktor.io/docs/migrating-2.html#server) there's no mention of why it was removed, and what should be used instead.

I am totally new to Ktor, and I am supposed to port a 1.6 project to 2 while learning Ktor from scratch. Some leads in this direction will be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Multiple DSL markers were [unified](https://github.com/ktorio/ktor/pull/2832) so you can use the [KtorDsl](https://api.ktor.io/ktor-utils/io.ktor.util/-ktor-dsl/index.html) annotation instead.